# Remote Push Notifications in React Native for both Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification

I am new to react native and I have built an app for magazines and catalogs which are loaded from my online hosting server (GoDaddy). I want to implement push notification in my app from that server on both android and IOS. Where should I begin and what are my options?

Comment: I use this for both Android and iOS: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

Comment: @HedeH - Does it will still works even when the app is completely closed i-e removed from app switcher?

Comment: do you need firebase mandatory for react-native-push-notification?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use services such as onesignal & fcm. Here i am sharing you some libaries for push notification

https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal (one signal)

You can use the below library for fcm, if you need any other firebase services such as authentication, dynamic links etc.. go for this

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase (fcm)

If you just need only push notification services, you can use

https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm

I personally suggest you the last one, because i am using this in all of my apps and enjoying better experience with it..

note : all the above has support for both android and ios

this article will be helpfull for integration

https://medium.com/differential/how-to-setup-push-notifications-in-react-native-ios-android-30ea0131355e

Edited in 2020, last repo suggested personally is no longer maintained now. It's deprecated, as said on their repository. For future viewers, please prefer the second last package, i.e. react-native-firebase (fcm)

Comment: Does all these will still works even when the app is completely closed i-e removed from app switcher?

Comment: yes, I had implemented react-native-firebase, it works fine in all the states of an app